# Can't Edit a Post

Tags: support, editing

I don't have the ability to edit [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/291559/terrible-ping-times-between-wireless-wired-subnets). First time I ran into this. I checked other questions and it seems I can edit them. Yes, I understand I can edit, but it won't save till a mod approves it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if it was because there was another edit pending.  I've approved that edit.  See if you can edit it now.

Comment: That would be it, many thanks and I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 3):

That's because there is already a pending edit on it. No one can edit that post until that pending is cleared.

Comment: People who can approve the pending edit can edit too... minor detail.